# Qualtrics: How to create a chart using altair visualization library

Tags: javascript, visualization, qualtrics, altair, vega-lite

I am trying to create a chart in Qualtrics using Altair (https://altair-viz.github.io) libraries. I can create a chart using other libraries such as chart.js but when I do the same procedure for Altair it doesn't work. This is how I am trying to create the chart:

In heading:

[heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBR11.png)

In html:
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7FxA.png)

In JS:
[javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAGW5.png)

Can anyone help me with this? Is it possible that Qualtrics does not support Altair?